# Javascript not working in mozilla firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

The following code is not working in mozilla firefox
   works well in chrome
  OS used is linux
 In the code i have been changing the topbar color and the contents of the taskbar after certain scroll  also there is a floating contact button to the left   which need to be shown after certain div element is passed .Thanks in advance

```
window.onscroll = function (oEvent) { //onscrool

var mydivpos = document.getElementById("aboutus").offsetTop;
var mydivpos2 = document.getElementById("mainlogo2").offsetTop;
var mydivpos3 = document.getElementById("home").offsetTop;
var scrollPos = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;

if(scrollPos >= mydivpos)
{
    document.getElementById("noshow").className = "";  //changin the classname
 }
else {
 document.getElementById("noshow").className = "hidden"; //the topbar which is need to show

}

if(scrollPos >= mydivpos2)
{
   document.getElementById("topbarwithlogo").className ="";
    document.getElementById("topbar").className = "hidden";
 }

if(scrollPos == 0)
{
   document.getElementById("topbar").className ="";
    document.getElementById("topbarwithlogo").className = "hidden";
 }

};




//HTML

<div id="noshow" class="hidden">
    <div class="appiphycontact">
                        <ul>      
                                    <img src="logos/facebook.png"   class="img-responsive">
                                            <img src="logos/google+.png" class="img-responsive">
                                            <img src="logos/Linkedin.png" class="img-responsive">
                                            <img src="logos/twitter.png" class="img-responsive"> 

                                    </ul>   

    </div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="topbar">
        <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span    class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-ar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>       
            </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul">
                    <li>
                        About Us
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Our Team
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    Our Clients
                    </li>                       
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

```
 <div class="container-fluid hidden" id="topbarwithlogo">
        <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

            </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="ul">
                    <li>
                        About Us
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Our Team
                    </li>

                    <li id="li">
                    Our Clients
                    </li>                       
                </ul>

            </div>
    </nav>
</div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="home">
  <div class="tinted-image">    

      <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="mainlogo2">
                                <img src="images/someimage.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>
                <div class="container-fluid">   
                    <div class="maincontent">
                            <div id="maincontent"><h1>.</h1> 
                                </div>

                 </div>
                </div>                   

     </div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid aboutus" id="aboutus">
            <div class="container">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p class="aboutusheader2">LEADER IN IT SERVICES, DIGITAL AND BUSINESS SOLUTIONS</p>
                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6 imagediv ">
                                <p id="aboutusinfo" >Some information.</p>          
                            </div>



                        <div class="col-md-6 imagediv">
                                    <div class="aboutusimg">
                                                    <ul>
                                                                <img src="images/someimage.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                                    <img src="images/someimage.png" class="img-responsive " alt="">
                                                            <img src="images/someimage.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                          </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: No there is no error in console

Comment: tried the firebug also

Comment: As the above code is working well in chrome

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us much. What do you see? And what is the HTML?

Comment: I just see a transparent topbar

Comment: Do you have `.hidden` in `css` ? You have not added `css` in the question.. Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @Rayon Dabre .hidden{ display:none;}

Comment: `home` and `mainlogo2` are not there in the `DOM`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre mainlogo conatains just the image

Comment: @JayShah, Whatever it it... It has to be there in the `DOM` to be selected..

Comment: Where is `mainlogo2` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Code has been updated

Comment: @RayonDabre the Code has been updated

Comment: @Rayon Dabre Code has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is something wrong with the if/else statements as the event is actually fired. If you add `console.debug("scrollevent fired");` at the beginning of the function and use firebug to show the console log, you will notice that the output is actually written to the output ([check the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c7fte5j/3/)).

Unfortunately I cannot debug your code as I cannot find a couple of elements with the given Id's in your code sample...

Comment: @Pazcasl which id u r not getting

Comment: If you check the JSFiddle, the console output says it cannot find the element with id 'aboutus', id 'mainlogo2' and id 'home'

Comment: I'sm still missing the element with id 'aboutus'